# Extract data between tags from files

Tags: xml, perl

Trying to extract data between tags using Perl. Unfortunately, parsers is not an option here because:

1. I need to have standard code to run against many files in a directory.
2. The content I need to extract is different in different files. For example: "Inclusion criteria" is   in  a `<P>` in one file, a `<L>` in another and in a `<TD>` in a third.

So, I'm really left with no option than to use a very kludgy way of using regular expressions to parse the file and extract the data. Unless someone has a better idea...

That said, I have the below code to do a search and extract in a file.

For a given phrase, I need to extract the content below it which can be a paragraph or a list `<L>`.

So this is what I am doing:

- Opening a File
- Find line containing phrase.
- Inspect if next line starts with a `<L>` tag, extract everything (range of lines) between `<L>` and `</LI>`  tags.

Below is my partial code. This does not return anything. So, looking for some help here.

1. Am I on the right track with this?
2. How I can extract the entire data between `<L>` and `</L>` tags and store it in an array for counting?

Snippet of code:

```
 if (($curr_line =~ m/\binclusion criteria\b/i)
  && ($curr_line !~ m/\b....\b/)  && ($curr_line !~   /^<Bookmark/) )
 {
    $nextline = <$CURR_FILE>
  if ($next_line =~ /^<L/)
    {
        print "next line is a list\n";
        ## inclusion is a list..so extract everything from the list
        my $start = "<LI>";
        my $end = "</L>";           
        while ($next_line =~ m{($start.*?$end)}gx)
        {
            print "List is...$next_line";

        }           

    }#inner if
     }
```

EDIT: Adding Input XML snippet.

So here is one of the XML files generated from a PDF.

I need to extract: "This is the study purpose content". Would be easy if only the path is consistent across all the documents. Here it is under: `//Sect//H4` but in others it is under `//Sect//H2` or `//Sect//H1`. There is no consistency here.

Also need to extract all the listed content under inlcusion and exlcusion criteria. Same issue. Path across documents is not consistent.

Bookmark links lead to a paragraph with unrelated content.

With such inconsistent XML, if I can still use a 1 parser program to extract information from thousands of docs, nothing like it. The only reason I'm going with a horrible kludgy and extremely inefficient search-and-extract program is because of the inconsistencies in the XML docs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>                                                            
<TaggedPDF-doc>  
  <bookmark-tree>
    <bookmark title="5.1.1 Inclusion criteria">
      <destination structID="LinkTarget_1130"/>
    </bookmark>
    <bookmark title="5.1.2 Exclusion criteria">
      <destination structID="LinkTarget_1131"/>
    </bookmark>
  </bookmark>
  <Part>
    <Sect>
      <Sect>
        <H4>2.1 Study purpose </H4>
        <P>This is study purpose content</P>
      </Sect>
      <P id="LinkTarget_1130"> This is some unrelated paragraph </P>
      <P>5.1.1 Inclusion criteria </P>
      <L>
        <LI>
          <LI_Label>1.  </LI_Label>
          <LI_Title>Title 1</LI_Title>
        </LI>
        <LI>
          <LI_Label>2.  </LI_Label>
          <LI_Title>Title 2 </LI_Title>
        </LI>
      </L>
      <P>some content 1</P>
      <P>some content 2</P>
      <P>some content 3 </P>
      <P>some content 4</P>
      <P>some content 5</P>
      <L>
        <LI>
          <LI_Label>4.</LI_Label>
          <LI_Title>Title 4</LI_Title>
        </LI>
        <LI>
          <LI_Label>5.  </LI_Label>
          <LI_Title>Title 5
        </LI>
      </L>
      <P id="LinkTarget_1131"> This is some unrelated paragraph </P>
      <P>5.1.2 Exclusion criteria </P>
      <P>Some content 1</P>
      <L>
        <LI>
          <LI_Label>1.  </LI_Label>
          <LI_Title>Title 1</LI_Title>
        </LI>
        <L>
          <LI>
            <LI_Label>2.    </LI_Label>
            <LI_Title>Title 2</LI_Title>
          </LI>
          <LI>(3) some content</LI>
        </L>
        <P>Some content </P>
      </Sect>
    </Sect>
  </Part>
</TaggedPDF-doc>
```

Comment: So, instead of using a real parser, you'd rather hack something *because* this would be standard?

Comment: Please show a short sample of each XML file. This can be done with a parser no problem.

Comment: Parsers is not an option here, parser are a solution here.

Comment: What does your input look like? This will help us determine the best way of parsing the file. Very likely, some sort of parser will work better than just regular expressions. A parser can get your data into a structure that can easily be traversed. Regular expressions will fail if some piece of data doesn't quite match your layout expectations. Even worse, the program will work for your tests, but fail when your job is on the line.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Updated my original post with a sample xml.

Comment: Um... are you... [parsing XML with regexes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: This isn't well-formed XML. The `<bookmark-tree>`-tag is “closed” by `</bookmark>`, and one `<L>`-tag is closed by `</Sect>`. You are correct, an XML parser is not an option here, but only because this isn't XML. — Anyway. Do I understand you correctly that you want the contents of the first `H1`, `H2`, `H3` or `H4` node that is below a `Sect`?

Comment: @amon: That might be my mistake when copy-pasting and formatting. Sorry about that. For all practical purposes, all the tags are well-closed. The problem is the consistency of text within the tags from document to document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is slightly contradictory, but I believe that an XPATH expression like

```
(//Sect//H1 | //Sect//H2 | //Sect//H3 | //Sect//H4)[1]/following-sibling::*
```

could do what you want. When run on a cleaned-up version of your “XML” like

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010; use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA); # XML is in DATA file handle

say $dom->findvalue('(//Sect//H1 | //Sect//H2 | //Sect//H3 | //Sect//H4)[1]/following-sibling::*');
```

it outputs

```
This is study purpose content
```

Comment: This can work for this particular value. But if I wanted to extract: 5.1.1 Inclusion criteria and all the children below it dynamically, how would I know where to stop? I'll need to only retrieve everything between <P>5.1.1 Inclusion criteria </P> and <P>5.1.2 Inclusion criteria </P>

Comment: @simak Then you should post more examples (removing unnecessary lines)

Answer (score 2):

Wrong. You should never read XML without using a proper XML parser, and the fact that your XML is complex and variable strengthens the case even more.

Clearly if there's no pattern at all to the data then you can't extract anything useful, whatever the programming language you use. But you must think there is some kind of pattern to it, otherwise you wouldn't attempt the task. So you need to tell us what that pattern is. For example, if you want the first following element after the first element whose name begins with "H", that would be

```
//*[starts-with(name(), 'H')][1]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Whatever the rule, if you can express it in English then you can express it in XPath (or if things get really tricky, in XSLT or XQuery).

Frankly, I think your difficulties here are that you are trying to hack it with code when you haven't thought about what rules you are trying to implement. That's doomed to failure in any programming language.